# Getting exception while using apply current values in mvc for updating the record

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, ado.net

I am creating a web service method and using apply current values in that case to update a record. I am getting exception:

> Error :- An object with a key that matches the key of the supplied object could not be found in the ObjectStateManager. Verify that the key values of the supplied object match the key values of the object to which changes must be applied.

Here is the code for the above:

```
        TestEntities db = new TestEntities();
        User user = new User();
        int userId = _userRepository.Find(x => x.UserId == userid).FirstOrDefault().Id;
        User existingUser = _userRepository.Find(x => x.Id == userId).SingleOrDefault();
        user = _userRepository.Find(x => x.Id == userId).SingleOrDefault();
        db.ApplyCurrentValues(existingUser.EntityKey.EntitySetName, user);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Exception comes whenever the break-point hits `ApplyCurrentValues` method.